# mysql update statement group by inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, inner-join

This statement used to work fine but not anymore. Nothing is changed. Is there an update to mysql?

Any comments to fix the query to make it work is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```sql
update table1 ac
join
(

SELECT category, count(id) as c_a 
FROM table2
WHERE some_condition=1 
group by category

) ca
on ac.cat_name=ca.category
set ac.id_count=ca.c_a;
```

Comment: What is the error now? Could you provide schema an data sample, please?

Comment: when i execute the query, it says 0 row is updated. table1 contains category list, table2 contains listings. my goal is to create a statement that can update the category table with the count of listings. this query used to work fine until this week, i don't know what happened. thanks

Comment: `Limit` a reserved word.  You need backticks around that at minimum.  If that's not the problem, please supply sample data and expected results.

Comment: so the goal is to create a query that can update the group by statement into another table

Comment: can you provide more details on "limit a reserved word"?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html -- some words are reserved words and if you want to use them as table names or column names, you have to escape them with back ticks.